How to print all lines that match the regex from the file?
Could you please tell me how can I print lines that matches a regex from a file?
In the topic:
Extract string matching regex from string
I only see how to print exact match, and when I use it to a file:
./xidel -e 'analyze-string(unparsed-text-lines("repl.k"), "uniq")//fn:match/text()'
I also see exact matches and when I remove //fn:match/text() It dumps all the file.
BTW: unparsed-text-lines probably stores all the lines in memory.
What should I do so the file could be read one line at a time?
Could you please advice? Thank you

"^.*uniq.*$" ?

What exactly do you mean by "that matches a regex"? Do you mean lines that match the regex in their entirety, or lines that contain a match?

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the question.
Also I'm not sure why you want to use a regex to match "uniq" when a simple contains() would suffice.
To get all the lines that contain "uniq" as a substring:
unparsed-text-lines("repl.k")[contains(., "uniq")]

To get all the lines equal to "uniq":
unparsed-text-lines("repl.k")[. = "uniq"]

To get all the lines that contain a substring that matches the regex "u*niq":
unparsed-text-lines("repl.k")[matches(., "u*niq")]

To get all the lines that in their entirety match the regex "u*niq":
unparsed-text-lines("repl.k")[matches(., "^u*niq$")]

(I suspect that you are relying too heavily on StackOverflow for your information about XQuery. You stumbled on a question where analyse-string() was the answer, and used this for a problem that doesn't need anything that powerful or complicated).
As for the question whether all the lines are stored in memory, that depends entirely on the XQuery implementation, and I don't know what Xidel does. Certainly Saxon will process the file one line at a time where (as here) the query allows it. In fact the reason unparsed-text-lines() was added to the function library was explicitly to make this easier to achieve.

Sorry for weird explanation. I wanted to check if I can do a oneliner as in perl -ne '/uniq/ and print' ./repl.k in Xquery. Thanks to your brilliant answer now I see that indeed it also can be short. Your example with matches is what I was looking for (because of regex) but I'll also look for contains and its application. I'll dig deeper. Thank you once again for awesome study material!

analyze-string(), that is.
